# Visual C# - Checking installed certificate - Does nothing if it doesnt exist

Tags: c#, winforms

This is probably a very basic error, but i am pulling my hair trying to understand why this is happening.

I have a check against the store certificates if it contains a certain certificate with a name. If it doesnt, then update a label.text. 
It does the check just fine and it finds it, but no matter what i do it doesnt handle if it isnt there. Its not doing anything. No text beeing displayed. I have also tried a simple else without the (!mCert) but still no go.

```
// Certificate controls
        X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
        {


            if (mCert.Issuer.Contains("Cert-Name"))
            {

                label3.Text = "Found certificate";
            }
                else if (!mCert.Issuer.Contains("Cert-Name"))

                {

                    label3.Text = "Didnt find the certificate";
                }


        }
```

So the else if statement isnt doing anything. Even if i just put an else instead there it isnt updating the label3.text.

Comment: Maybe if there are no certificates tnen store.Certificates will be empty and the foreach won't even start. Try to add a breakpoint on the foreach to debug and check what's inside the variables

Comment: Why do you even check `if (!mCert.Issuer.Contains("Cert-Name"))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the store is empty and cant find any certificates the foreach will never run, thats why the if statements never get processed.

Adding this before the foreach will solve it

```
          if (store.Certificates.Count==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

"My" store of local machine is very likely to be empty (unless you install things such as IIS, where the installer generates test certificates).

Thus, switch to other stores, such as using `StoreName` enumeration,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename(v=vs.110).aspx

You can always open MMC to see stores and certificates,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Tried but then it couldnt find the certificate at all. Only if i use MY as storename i can find it. But when i remove it the label3.text is just empty ...

Comment: Revised the answer. You should use the `StoreName` enumeration instead of hardcoded store names.